# Ember - prevent transition on route error

Tags: javascript, ember.js, error-handling, url-routing

I am intercepting the `error` hook on my ember routes. I am doing this on top level and inheriting all my routes from this class.

What I want to do is, when the server returns a **401 Unauthorized** response, I want to display a notice saying the user is not authorized, and stay on the same page.

So far I have this:

```
Ember.Route = Ember.Route.extend(InfinityRoute, {
  actions: {
    error: function(error){
      if (error.status === 401) {
        this.store.createRecord('notice', {
          message: "You are not authorized to view this content. Sorry man."
        });
        // Some code here ...
      }
    }
  }
});
```

The notice works, but the application still switches to the new template, which has empty content because the user does not have authorization to view it.

I want my application to stay on the same page and not transition to the requested page.

How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly but you can try `willTransition`:

```
willTransition: function(transition) {
  // inspect transition object to see if the error ocurred
}
```

Maybe it'll help :)